# is it possible to find a small image in a big image faster than this way?

Tags: c++, image, compare

I need to get the coordinate of a image on the screen.
I use gdi to capture the screen to get big image data, and load small image data from file.
I compare two images with follow code,but it is too slow.
Is it possible to find a faster way? And the way is no loss of accuracy.
Beacause i tried gray transform and comapre the hash of every column and other ways, they are faster but not precise.

```C++
// input:big image,samll image,sim,dfcolor,rc
// output:a POINT,{-1,-1} means not found
PBYTE pSrc = _src.getBytes(); // _src is big image, pSrc is big image data pointer
PBYTE pPic = pic->getBytes(); // pic is small image, pPic issamll image data pointer
int max_error = (1. - sim) * pic->width() * pic->height();
int error_count = 0;
bool bad = false;
// rc is a rect,because use multithreading,every thread handle a block of big image
for (int i = rc.y1; i < rc.y2; ++i) {
    for (int j = rc.x1; j < rc.x2; ++j) {
        // stop is a std::atomic_bool variable,to notify other threads to stop if found
        if (stop) {
            return { -1, -1 };
        }
        // image data is stored as bgra,i just compare rgb
        // dfcolor is color deviation
        for (int y1 = 0; y1 < pic->height() && !bad; ++y1) {
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < pic->width(); ++x1) {
                int index1 = ((i + y1) * _src.width() + j + x1) << 2; 
                int index2 = (y1 * pic->width() + x1) << 2;
                if (abs(*(pSrc + index1) - *(pPic + index2)) >= dfcolor.b ||
                    abs(*(pSrc + index1 + 1) - *(pPic + index2 + 1)) >= dfcolor.g ||
                    abs(*(pSrc + index1 + 2) - *(pPic + index2 + 2)) >= dfcolor.r) {
                    ++error_count;
                    if (error_count > max_error) { 
                        bad = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // not found,continue
        if (bad) {
            error_count = 0;
            bad = false;
            continue;
        }
        // found
        stop = true;
        return { i, j };
    }
}
return { -1,-1 };
```

Comment: Where's the function declaration?

Comment: You are testing every pixel of the image in order using 3 branches for your if condition. Try comparing the sum of the 3 `abs` to a threshold. Also try comparing the border or a diagonal of the image or a (random) subset of pixels to rule out cases where e.g. the first half of the image matches. Or build a mipmap and try finding lower resolution copies of the image first.

Comment: @ThomaMatthews The complete code is too long. This is the core code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how smart your compiler is, but your `index1` and `index2` in the innermost loop (VERY nested) are advancing by 4 bytes in each iteration.

You could simply calculate pointers into your `Src` and `Pic` images and advance those instead of pretty complicated math.

The effects are at least two-folds: you may save some time on that math AND (more important) compiler may notice that it can vectorize that if statement.